# Обобщенные типы в С#

Tags: c#, generics, c#-faq

```
public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Myclass<Testclass> ob = new Myclass<Testclass>();
    }


    class Myclass<T> where T: new()
    {
        public T instanse = new T();
    }
    class Testclass { }
}
```

**Вопрос**: `Myclass` - это тип. `Testclass` - тоже тип. Какого же тогда типа экземпляр `ob`?

Comment: как ни странно, но `Myclass<Testclass>`

Comment: тогда еще вопрос: зачем двойной тип?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MyClass` — это как бы не совсем тип. Это *обобощённый* тип (на английском — generic).

Вы можете сконструировать экземпляр обобщённого типа только указав типы-аргументы, которые заменят формальный параметр-тип `T`. Экземпляр обобщённого типа *самого по себе* сконструировать невозможно.

Для каждого обобщённого типа существует (обычно бесконечно много) конкретизаций: конкретных типов, которые соответствуют определённым значениям типов-параметров.

Соответственно, тип `ob` и есть такая конкретизация: `Myclass` с параметром `T = Testclass`. Такая конкретизация в языке C# записывается как `Myclass<Testclass>`.

Comment: Если нужен какой-то новый тип - можно создать новый класс - и, пожалуйста - новый тип. Зачем такие параметризованные выкрунтасы? Самое главное - для чего?

Comment: @Proshka: Как обычно — чтобы избежать дублирования кода. Если у вас есть, например, список `int`'ов и список `char`'ов, вам, поверьте, не захочется дублировать код списка с одним только различающимся типом элемента.

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: @Proshka: Пожалуйста, рад, что помогло.

Comment: Не обессудьте - люблю копать до последнего, до исключительно полного понимания процесса. А иначе нет смысла в изучении через пень/колоду

Comment: @Proshka: И это здорово! В основах нужно разбираться _основательно_.

Answer (score 1):

Неточность заключается в том, что в приведенном коде нет типа/класса `Myclass`

Есть `Myclass<T>` - класс с generic-параметром.

При создании указывается конкретный `T`: `Myclass<Testclass>`

и переменная получает этот тип: `Myclass<Testclass>`

Comment: получается, переменная типа Testclass? Или типа Myclass<Testclass>?

Comment: @Proshka, _типа Myclass<Testclass>_